# no postback after clicking on button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here I need to pass two values those are customer id which will be taken when customer logs in and product id which will be added when customer clicks on particular product. 
I have added AddToWishList button near product details page. When I click on add to wish list button, it does nothing.

Here is my code.

```
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int customerId, wishlistId = 0, productId;
        if (Session["customerId"] != null)
        {
            customerId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);
            productId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProductId"].ToString());
            wishlistId = AddToWish(customerId, productId);
            MessageLabel.Text = "Your Request has been Sent Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageLabel.Text = "Some Error Occured";
        }
    }

    private int AddToWish(int customerId, int productId)
    {
        int wishlistId;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Insert into WishList (ProductID, CustomerID) values (@ProductID, @CustomerID);Select @@Identity";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", productId);
        wishlistId = DbUtility.UpdateDbGetIdentity(command);
        return wishlistId;
    }
}


WishList Database Table

WishListId PK
ProductID
CustomerID
```

Aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div id="DetailsView">
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="378px"
        DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AutoGenerateRows="False">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" SortExpression="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="ProductName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemsInSet" HeaderText="Items In Set" SortExpression="ItemsInSet" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPriceOwner" HeaderText="Unit Price Owner" SortExpression="UnitPriceOwner" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPriceReseller" HeaderText="Unit Price Reseller" SortExpression="UnitPriceReseller" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="Category ID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShippingCost" HeaderText="Shipping Cost" SortExpression="ShippingCost" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="InOffer" HeaderText="In Offer" SortExpression="InOffer" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Visible" HeaderText="Visible" SortExpression="Visible" />

            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="BookingPage.aspx?ProductID={0}" 
                HeaderText="Buy" Text="Add to Cart" />
            </Fields>         
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFC0" Font-Bold="True" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add To Wishlist" CssClass="myButton" OnClick="Button1_Click" AutoPostBack="true"/>

     <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UmmatiConStr %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Description, ItemsInSet, UnitPriceOwner, UnitPriceReseller, CategoryID, ShippingCost, InOffer, Visible FROM Products WHERE (ProductID = @ProductID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="ProductID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you define and assign the Connection for the command?

Comment: Set the postback attribute of the button to true.

Comment: @un-lucky Its probably in `DbUtility.UpdateDbGetIdentity`

Comment: Yes DbUtility.UpdateDbGetIdentity. I have defined there.

Comment: Did you check by setting the `PostBack` to `true`?

Comment: Yes tried. Still does nothing

Comment: Can you add the aspx code too?

Comment: how do you know nothing happens?

Comment: The code you added is fine, put the breakpoint in your method `AddToWish()` and check if it hits. If it does, it means the issue is in your `DbUtility.UpdateDbGetIdentity()` method.

Comment: put the breakpoint in AddtoWIsh(). When I run and click add to wish list button, it doesnt taking to me code page..I am not able to debug my code.

Comment: Was the session value null? or perhaps there's any client-side errors that prevented the postback?